# What doubts around the legality of the US coalition's actions in the Red Sea has the Russian representative Vasily Nebenzya exactly?

Tags: united-states, international-law, international-waters, law-of-the-sea

Reading [this](https://www.shorouknews.com/news/view.aspx?cdate=04012024&id=fbd49930-73b3-437e-8fa1-74180167559a) (translated), on what the Russia's Permanent Representative in the UN Security Council, Vasily Nebenzya, said at the meeting:

> Nebenzia said: “The so-called international maritime alliance formed
> by Washington, despite its loud name, (Guardian of Prosperity), is in
> fact mostly composed of warships belonging to the United States
> itself, and the legality of its actions from the point of view of
> international law raises very serious doubts,” he reported.

Based on what grounds is the Russian Representative doubting the legality of the US coalition's actions in the Red Sea? Is there an international law that he thinks the coalition might be breaking?

Comment: The way the question is formulated is about *doubts* and hypothetical*. There is a seed of a good question here, but it requires a bit more research.

Comment: @RogerV. These aren't my words!. In fact, I am questioning his claim.

Comment: Depends what you think the actions in the Red Sea actually **are** (and remember that what the Russian representative believes may not seem rational)  If you think the US is heading a coalition to defend international shipping against Houthi pirates, then your application of "international law" will be very different to someone who thinks the US is setting up an attack force for the invasion of Iran, in preparation for a pincer attack on Russia from both the South and the West.

Comment: Sure there will be some doubts by someone. The world is quite big. Is there anything that is not doubted by someone? The question in the body about the doubts of the Russian representative is much more specific and may be answered with more information.

Comment: @JamesK " defend international shipping against Houthi pirates" - nuke-missile submarine Ohio vs "pirates" looks a little bit of... excessively?

Comment: @άνθρωπος Well yes... that is kind of the point. There is a disconnect between what the Russia and America say, and their actions.  The sub is more likely a cruise missile armed sub rather than part of the ballistic missile fleet  (the US isn't going to let anybody know where it's ballistic missiles subs, and certainly not have them float visibly through suez canal, they are too strategically important for that)

Comment: @JamesK im enjoying your sure with "more (highly-)likely" 
unverifiable information. Even the US moved a missile armed-variant sub + modern aircraft carrier group... So, what is it, i have only a sarcastic dilemma: "Throwing beads in front of pigs" or "shooting a cannon at sparrows"? Any of two does not look truthfully. But what of goes do you like?

Comment: I don't understand why the question has 2 Close votes. What guidline(s) doesn't this question meet?

Comment: @άνθρωπος armed forces aren't in the business of "fair fights". Bringing in a weapon system that the pirates have no countermeasures for is a desirable state. The relevant decisioning is going to be along the lines of "do we need these vessels elsewhere?"

Comment: That is just a joke, another close vote, this time is asking for clarity, how much clearer can it get? It is a simple question!